# Find Pattern in arrays

Tags: algorithm

I have two sub-sequences of values and the values can be 0, -1 and 1. 
The values reprensent the slope, 0 for null, -1 for negative one and 1 for positive one. 
I want to join the two sub-sequences and build the sequence that represent the "union" of the two sub-sequences.

Example here : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mwbj.png)

a1 = [0 -1 0 1] and r1 = [0 -1 0] give me p1 = [0 -1 0 1]

a2 = [-1 0] and r2 = [0 1] give me p2 = [-1 0 1]

But i cannot find an algorithm working well. In fact the problem is that the values are not unique so the union doesn't do well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Baptiste.

Comment: Your example is not clear, and it doesn't seem to be the standard definition of *intersection*. Can you please explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have two sub-sequences of values and the values can be 0, -1 and 1. I want to join the two sub-sequences and build the sequence that represent the "union" of the two sub-sequences.

Comment: Are the values in the array unique? Or is it possible that a1, for example, looks like that: [0 1 1]?

Comment: The values in the array are not necessarily unique.

Comment: But in the result the values have to be unique, right?
EDIT: Nevermind. Now I get it

Comment: No for example if i have a1 = [0 1 1] and r1 = [-1 0] p1 should be [-1 0 1 1]

Comment: You should edit the question it is totally unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHNyR.jpg) is an idea how you could solve your problem <strike>(assuming a2 is the smaller array, otherwise just swap)</strike>(actually, it should be irrelevant which array is larger)

Comment: Thank you, looking for the best score match will give me the sequence.